# IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized while MapsInitializer.initialize(context) is called since Google Play Services v9.6

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have upgraded to Google Play Services [v9.6](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), but now i'm getting a exception if i try to use classes such like `BitmapDescriptorFactory`.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: nl.rsdt.japp, PID: 3117
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.zzbsg(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(Unknown Source)
                  at nl.rsdt.japp.jotial.maps.management.controllers.FotoOpdrachtController$FotoOpdrachtTransducer.generate(FotoOpdrachtController.java:164)
                  at nl.rsdt.japp.jotial.maps.management.controllers.FotoOpdrachtController$FotoOpdrachtTransducer.transduceToBundle(FotoOpdrachtController.java:125)
                  at nl.rsdt.japp.jotial.maps.management.transformation.async.AsyncBundleTransduceTask.doInBackground(AsyncBundleTransduceTask.java:31)
                  at nl.rsdt.japp.jotial.maps.management.transformation.async.AsyncBundleTransduceTask.doInBackground(AsyncBundleTransduceTask.java:15)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

In the previous version(v.9.4) calling `MapsInitializer.initialize(context);` would enable me to use classes such as `BitmapDescriptorFactory`. But now it doesn't? I have tried `MapsInitializer.initialize(context);` witch my Application Context and with my Activity Context but both result in the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has resolved it self for me, you can see the Issue i made on the Issue Tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10554).